# Alternative to subprocess mv to reduce memory footprint

Tags: python, subprocess

How would I do the following in a more pythonic way that doesn't create a new thread (which takes up too much memory for me) --

```
subprocess.call(['mv', '/tmp/%s' % self.file_name, self.file_name])
```

Also, I need to make sure it respects the `sudo` command when running the script, because I need that in order to move the file.

Comment: What do you mean by  'doesn't create a new thread?'

Comment: @pvg the `os.fork` -- `subprocess.call(['mv', self.file_name, '/tmp/%s' % self.file_name])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
  return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1223, in _execute_child
  self.pid = os.fork()`

Comment: Have you looked into `os.rename` and `shutil.move`?

Comment: You mean it forks another process? Well, yeah it will do that. If you don't want that, don't use subprocess, use something like `os.rename`.

Comment: About your second point (sudo), you can check that your script has been called as root (e.g., using sudo), by checking if `os.geteuid()` is 0 and raise an error message accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with some more details on what, specifically, you're trying to accomplish and what your constraints are (apparently, forking out `mv` uses too much memory). The 'pythonic' thing seems like a bit of a red herring, there's nothing unpythonic about launching subprocesses. Or not, if you don't want to.

Comment: @pvg updated title

Comment: @LucaCiti: On Py 3.3+, assuming you want to replace existing destination files, [`os.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace) is a better choice, since the behavior is consistent on both Windows and UNIX-like systems.

Comment: @pvg: It's unpythonic to launch subprocesses when the included batteries can do it for you, with similar speed, more safety, better error reporting, and simpler usage (for example, this "simple" use of `mv` won't properly report a failure to perform the move to the program, `subprocess.check_call`/`subprocess.check_output` would do so, but they wouldn't be able to report the details of the problem like a Python library could, because the details of the error encountered by the subprocess aren't exposed in a consistent way).

Comment: @ShadowRanger You might really want to fork out a `mv`. There is nothing inherently unpythonic about that and the goals were not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you're performing is best done [using `shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move), which will run with the same privileges as your Python process (because it *is* your Python process), so if the Python script is `sudo`ed, so is the `move` operation:

```
import shutil

shutil.move('/tmp/%s' % self.file_name, self.file_name)
```